# Remove empty badges block in profile page

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page, new-users

There's no need to show empty block named "Badges" for new users, like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1101391/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2?tab=profile):

> [image: Empty Badges]

Comment: I would think the better way would be to write "This user hasn't earned any badges yet".